# Integral - log partition function

Tags: calculus, probability

I am studing the exponential family - and trying to understand the flow of formulas per below. In my book it is defined that $A(\theta)=\log \int \left(h(x) \exp \theta^T \phi(x) \right)$

In the formulas per below - i don't understand how the denominator between 9.28 and 9.29 goes from $\int \left(\exp \theta^T \phi(x) h(x) \right)$ to $exp(A(\theta))$ , as this would in my mind imply that $A(\theta)= \int \left(h(x) \exp \theta^T \phi(x) \right)$ ?

i am probably making an elementary mistake - any quick tip much appreciated

[image]

(please let me know if it is norm on this forum to write out all formulas in these cases in Mathjax)

Comment: What kind of object is $\theta$? a number? a matrix? something else?

Comment: $\theta$ would be a vector of parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the definition of $A$ given as

$$A(\theta)\equiv\log\left(\int h(x)e^{\theta\phi(x)}dx\right)\tag 1$$

Let  $z(\theta)\equiv\int h(x)e^{\theta\phi(x)}dx$ so that $A(\theta)=\log z(\theta)$.  Then, inasmuch as $e^{\log z}=z$, we have

$$\begin{align}
e^{A(\theta)}&=e^{\log z(\theta)}\\\\
&=\int h(x)e^{\theta\phi(x)}dx\tag2
\end{align}$$

From the text, Equation $(9.28)$ is

$$\frac{\frac{d}{d\theta}\int h(x)e^{\theta\phi(x)}dx }{\int h(x)e^{\theta\phi(x)}dx}\tag{9.28}$$

Note that the denominator in $(9.28)$ is $z(\theta)$, which is from $(2)$ equal to $e^{A(\theta)}$.

Comment: The definition, as given in the body of the problem, involves $\theta^T$, whereas the version of the definition in this answer doesn't. So, what's up with that?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Look at the post again and you will see that the notation in the equations that were pasted do not have that notation.  So, just curious, but what is your issue?  It does not affect anything.

Comment: My issue is that OP writes, "In my book it is defined that..." and then gives a formula that has $\theta^T$, while you write, "We have the defintion of $A$ given as..." and then you give a formula that doesn't have $\theta^T$. Are you actually defining the same thing the book is defining? It's not immediate to me that the two formulas are defining the same thing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Again, look at the excerpt from the book (Equations 9.26 - 9.31).  There is no superscript.  And even if there were, how does this affect the development that the author presented?

Comment: I know what the excerpt says. I also know what OP wrote. The development the author presented --- would it still be right if the definition had $\theta^T$ in it?